# VSCode terminal is using the wrong python version

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have a new mac with python 3 installed from homebrew and visual studio code. I am not a python person by default I tend to use java but wanted to try a project for fun.

Just my terminal in VSCode has a system install of python 3.8 version that I am not using I want to use my brew install version as shown in screen shots. if I do echo $path it shows correct, my mac terminal shows correct and my VSCode python plugin has the correct version showing. I have rebooted several times in case it was cached.

I want to use the brew version 3.9.7. My project is failing to load imports such as "import requests" I assume because of this. The import fail error is.

Import "requests" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource

I have installed and uninstalled requests many times always through VSCode command line.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you [installed requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/) with the pip3 program associated with your chosen python version?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67367070/vs-code-doesnt-see-the-installed-modules/67367998#67367998 might help you

Comment: Pip3 from my mac command line points to the correct brew 3.9 version I want but from VSCode terminal it does not it points to some system version of 3.8.  Why does my vscode terminal not inherit my correct path same as my mac terminal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode terminal shows incorrect python version and path, launching terminal from anaconda works perfectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54582361/vscode-terminal-shows-incorrect-python-version-and-path-launching-terminal-from)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the values in `$PATH` of VS Code is in a different order than that of Terminal.app.

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/70248 for more informations.

You can simply set `"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false`. This works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the following in settings.json:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
        "PATH": ""
}
```

Save the file, close any terminal window and restart VS Code.

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54582361/vscode-terminal-shows-incorrect-python-version-and-path-launching-terminal-from).

Answer (score 0):

Go into VS Code settings: Code->Preferences->Settings. Type the following in the search box:

```
terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false
```

Uncheck the option box beside the setting "whether new shells should inherit their environment from VS Code..." to set it to False.

Restart VS code and try again, you should have the same version of python as on your standard terminal.